# From C++ to C# with Pcap files

Tags: c#, c++, pcap, pcap.net

I have a program written in C++ and I have to convert it to C#.
This program reads some pcap files.
I have add a reference to the PcapDotNet library in my new C# project but the types are not the same as in C++, like:

```
pcap_t *fp;
char[] errbuf = new char[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
pcap_pkthdr header;
```

So I don't know what is the best way to proceed, find the corresponding types with C#, or import the DLL. I found in fact that many do it in the following way:

```
//pcap_t *fp;
[DllImport("wpcap.dll")]
static extern int fp;
```

but for now it doesn't work and it gives me error.
It doesn't see DllImport and says that a `;` is missing, then also on the line below it says `Invalid expression term 'static'` and `';' expected`.

The thing is, I don't have any devices or anything, the original C++ program just reads these pcap files extract the data ad does something else with it.

Comment: @ayasha, what is the error?

Comment: It will be easier to find the C# types, otherwise you will need to marshal things. BTW Is your static inside a class? If not you will get errors.

Comment: the problem is that i dont know if some functions exist or not..like the header pcap_pkthdr, i dont think it exists in c#, same for the function pcap_next_ex or pcap_open_offline..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use [Pcap.Net](http://pcapdot.net) to read pcap files, you can just follow the instructions in the [Pcap.Net User Guide](https://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Pcap.Net%20User%20Guide&referringTitle=Home).

Specifically, see "Reading packets from a dump file" [here](https://pcapdotnet.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Pcap.Net%20Tutorial%20-%20Handling%20offline%20dump%20files&referringTitle=Pcap.Net%20User%20Guide).